# How can I make a method to get a birthday date

Tags: java, loops, file, class, object

Hello everyone I am currently making a program to try and compare student birthday dates to see which birthday is closest to the requested student.The program I have so far takes in a file input and puts it in a array called student.My problem is after putting the info in the array I am having trouble implementing my method getBirthdayVal(). I don't know how to go about creating a method that will compare the month and the days. Here is what I have so far.

```
package Project1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Birthday extends Student {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("birthdayInputFile.txt"));
        int days = 1;
        int numClass = input.nextInt();
        for(int classCount = 1; classCount<numClass;classCount++) {
            System.out.println("Day#: " + days + "\n");
            int numStudents = input.nextInt();
            Student student[] = new Student[numStudents];
            for(int i = 0; i <student.length;i++) {
                String firstName = input.next();
                String lastName = input.next();
                int month = input.nextInt();
                int day = input.nextInt();
                int year = input.nextInt();
                Student students = new Student(firstName,lastName,month,day,year);
                student[i] = students;

                }
            for(int x = 1; x < student.length;x++) {
                Student temp = student[x];
                int before = x - 1;
                while(before >= 0 && (student[before].getBirthdayVal() > temp.getBirthdayVal())) {
                    student[before + 1] = student[before];
                    before = before-1;
                }
                student[before + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }


}
// Here is the other file in the package.
package Project1;
import java.util.*;

public class Student {


        String fName;
        String lName;
        String fullName;
        int month;;
        int day;
        int year;


        Student ()
        {

        }
        Student (String first, String last,int month, int day, int year)
        {
            this.fName = first;
            this.lName = last;
            this.fullName = first + " " + last;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
            this.year = year;


        }


        void setName(String first, String last)
        {
            this.fName = first;
            this.lName = last;
            this.fullName = first + " " + last;
        }


        String getName(Birthday b)
        {
            return this.fullName;
        }
        String getFName()
        {
            return this.fName;
        }
        String getLName()
        {
            return this.lName;
        }
        int getMonth() {
            return this.month;
        }
        int getDay() {
            return this.day;
        }
        public  void getBirthdayVal() { // part I'm confused on. I don't know how to implement what I want to do


        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't an answer but a general comment - from an OO perspective a Birthday isn't a type of Student which is what you have modelled, rather a Student has a Birthday. If you modelled it that way it might actually be easier, if each student has a Birthday and each Student has a method to provide the days difference between their Birthday date and some given date (implemented by calling a method on Birthday to compare the dates in a Demeter style)

Comment: Actually no need for a Birthday class, just Students with a LocalDate property called birthday